# Magento 2 Main Price Updated when select associated Product and update dynamic price

Tags: magento-2.1, price, bundled-product

On Bundle Product :

When Select Associated products from Bundle Product Price updated [image]

This Things are default functionality of magento but I want to update same price with main Price which shows on Top price box section as per below :
[image]

Any Idea how to update price "from - to" Price?